# OS X Password Bruteforce in Python

Tags: python, macos, sha1

I have my old macbook from a few years back, I don't remember the password exactly but I do recall some of the characters from my password at the time so I was thinking I could probably get the rest using a version of a script that's readily available.  The problem is that when I test on a hash for "password" with the string that's in the example I get a different value than the hash provided. As such I'll never be able to get my old password. Here is the relevant code pulled from http://pastebin.com/Gv6VxEZ7

```
#Should be 8 characters of salt + sha hash for "password" if I'm understanding this correctly
digest = "33BA7C74C318F5D3EF40EB25E1C42F312ACF905E20540226"
salt = "33BA7C74"
sha1 = "C318F5D3EF40EB25E1C42F312ACF905E20540226"

try:
    salt_hex =  chr(int(salt[0:2], 16)) + chr(int(salt[2:4], 16)) + chr(int(salt[4:6], 16)) + chr(int(salt[6:8], 16)) # CONVERT SALT TO HEX

check("password", salt_hex, salt)

def check(password,salt_hex, salt): # HASH PASS AND COMPARE

    if not password.startswith("#!"): #IGNORE COMMENTS
            sha1_guess = hashlib.sha1(salt_hex+password).hexdigest()
            print("Trying with salt_hex " + password)
            print sha1_guess.upper()
            print "\n"
            sha1_guess = hashlib.sha1(salt+password).hexdigest()
            print("Trying with salt " + password)
            print sha1_guess.upper()
            print "\n"
            if sha1 in sha1_guess.upper():
                    print("Cleartext password is : "+password)
                    exit(0)
```

Unfortunately the output from both of these attempts is incorrect

$ python sha_crack.py

Attempting to crack...  33BA7C74C318F5D3EF40EB25E1C42F312ACF905E20540226

Trying with salt_hex password
9D8F0A15CF344F7FB35A1918AA0636A025261627

Trying with salt password
E105192888CC1C34B7535AAA0425EC06F653A1B9

Article I was working from to test showing that this hash is for "password"

http://www.defenceindepth.net/2009/12/cracking-os-x-passwords.html

Comment: Not entirely sure that's a genuine example.

Comment: You seem to be discarding the `salt_hex+password` guess without comparing it to anything.

Answer (score 0):

The sample hash you're using is simply incorrect.

If we take instead a test vector provided in [JtR wiki](http://openwall.info/wiki/john/sample-hashes), we'll see that code works as expected (correct password is "`macintosh`" as per Wiki):

```
import binascii
import hashlib

hash = "0E6A48F765D0FFFFF6247FA80D748E615F91DD0C7431E4D9"
salt = binascii.unhexlify(hash[0:8])
sha1 = binascii.unhexlify(hash[8:])

passwords = ["123", "password", "macintosh"]
for password in passwords:
    if hashlib.sha1(salt + password).digest() == sha1:
        print "Password is \"%s\"" % password
        break
```

Comment: Thanks, I just assumed I was using something incorrectly. Never would have guessed that the hash was wrong.